# How can I set my local date in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to get the difference between today date and my data date from database

I notice every day at 3 pm . next day start
( for example if today is 20 . at 3 pm the date will be 21 )

```
  const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var serverDate = new Date(value)
  let todayDate = new Date()
  const difference = Math.round(Math.abs((todayDate - serverDate) / oneDay));
  return difference
```

How can I set my local date or there is better way to solve this problem

Comment: important question: why does your code assume your server and you are in the same time zone?

Answer (score 2):

You can get your local time by passing your location with localeString.

```
var asiaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Shanghai" 
});
asiaTime = new Date(asiaTime);
console.log('Asia time in string: ' + asiaTime.toLocaleString())
console.log('Asia time in Date format', asiaTime)

var aestTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: 
"Australia/Brisbane"});
aestTime = new Date(aestTime);
console.log('AEST time: '+aestTime.toLocaleString())
console.log('AEST time in Date format', aestTime)

var indiaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: 
"Asia/Kolkata"});
indiaTime = new Date(indiaTime);
console.log('India time: '+indiaTime.toLocaleString())
console.log('Inida time in Date format', indiaTime)
```

Hope this Helps . GOOD LUCK.

Comment: still the problem at 3 pm ( right now ) - now the day is 21

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the difference between the current and your DB date run the below code.

```js
var d = new Date();
var currentDate = moment(d.toLocaleString(),'M/D/YYYY');
var systemDate = moment('2/20/2019','M/D/YYYY');
var diffDays = currentDate.diff(systemDate, 'days');


 console.log("diffDays",diffDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```